# Как задать два действия на клик по одной кнопке?

Tags: javascript

Есть контактная форма, в ней кнопка submit, она отправляет данные.
Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на нее выполнялась основная функция отправки данных, а так же действие по клику, который по приложенному JS-скрипту показывает скрытый блок. 
**Проблема:** выполняется только скрипт, который показывает скрытый блок, а отправка информации игнорируется. 
При это никакого конфликта скриптов в консоли не наблюдается. Как исправить проблему?

```js
//Показать спасибо за заказ
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var btn = document.querySelector('.btn-soobmit');
 btn.onclick = function(e) {
  var element = document.querySelector(".thank-you-form");
   if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
    element.classList.remove("show-block");
   } else {
    element.classList.add("show-block");
   }
 }
 });
 
 //плавный скролл при выборе поломки вниз к "спасибо"
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
(() => {
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.thank-you-form');

const handler = () => {
    [...tabs].map(tab => tab.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' }));
  };

  for (let cbox of document.querySelectorAll('.btn-soobmit')) {
    cbox.addEventListener('click', handler);
  }
})();
});
```

```css
.show-block {
display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<input name="qfsubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-soobmit" value="Отправить" onclick="this.form.submit()">
<br>-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
-<br>
<div class="thank-you-form" style="display: none;">
Спасибо за заявку, начальник!
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: что мешает при клике на кнопку вызвать 2 функции?
и я у вас в коде не вижу функцию отправки формы?

Comment: какой чудный плод любви между jquery и javascript

Comment: @MaximLensky поясните, пожалуйста)

Comment: у Вас есть объявление jquery и так же инструкции присущие только ванильному javascript

Comment: @MaximLensky это неправильно?

Comment: ну разумеется `не правильно` надо использовать либо одно либо другое

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/WNNYjGK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(() => {
  const thankYouBlock = document.querySelector(".thank-you-form");

  document.querySelector(".btn-soobmit").addEventListener("click", () => {
    thankYouBlock.classList.toggle("show-block");

    thankYouBlock.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
  });
})();
```